# Controlling external web pages with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I came here with this question because honestly I don't know were to start. I'm aware that Javascript can do a lot of good stuff in my own web page, actually I use Jquery. However, I came to a point in my project that I need to introduce information in a web page that is not mine (external web page, if it can be called that way), simulate that I press a button to get an answer, and store that answer in my database. The external page does not have an API, nor a web service or something similar. I know about the load method in Jquery but it doesn't seem to me the right way. I just need to know what to investigate or to learn, just a clue so I can build it from my own. Sorry if the question is repeated but I tried my best to search. Also, English is not my first language.

Comment: Sounds like you want to "crawl" a website, or use something like PhantomJs to automate a repetitive process.

Comment: You need to crawl the external web page

Comment: Do you mean maybe there is a button and a text field on your page, and when the user press that button down, it will send the value of text field to another web page?

Comment: @Hanslen, not only send the value, but actually interact with another web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of argument, let us say that the "external webpage" is my online banking, or my webmail … and that the button presses you want to simulate are "send you all my money" or "read all my email".

Given that, it should be pretty obvious that this should be, and is, impossible.

See [the Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) for further reading on the subject.

---

If you want to do this, you can't use browser side code (your mention of jQuery implies that is where you expect the JS to run).

Use a language that runs in an environment you control (e.g. your own server). That could be JavaScript (e.g. via Node.js). HTTP request libraries are available for just about every language out there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @Quentin. I already read the Same Origin Policy, and that helps a lot. In your update you mention that I can use a language running in my own server. That will allow me to request that "external" web page and work on it as if I was an average user of that external web page simulating events such as introducing text or click an object?